# Magento Product creation - Integrity constraint violation

Tags: php, mysql, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.7

I am using a php script to create new product and update existing products in Magento 1.7.0.2.
This script working fine with single or few 100's of products. If create or update large number of products, say 5000 , gets following error

**SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magento_live`.`catalog_product_entity_varchar`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_VCHR_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON D)**

The script which I used,

```
const DEFAULT_STORE_ID=0;
    const DEFAULT_VISIBILITY=4;
    const DEFAULT_TAXCLASS=2;   

    /**
     * @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
     */
    protected $magentoProduct;
    protected $errors=array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(0);
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'adminhtml'));
        $userModel=Mage::getModel('admin/user');
        $userModel->setUserId(1);
        $session=Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
        $session->setUser($userModel);
        $session->setAcl(Mage::getResourceModel('admin/acl')->loadAcl());
    }

    public function getErrors()
    {
        return $this->errors;
    }

    public function save($productData)
    {
        $start=microtime(true);
        $this->magentoProduct=Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $magentoProductId=$this->magentoProduct->getIdBySku($productData['sku']);
        $this->magentoProduct->load($magentoProductId);

        if (!$this->magentoProduct->getId())
        {
        mage::log("ADDING sku-" . $productData['sku']);
           try
            { 

            $this->magentoProduct->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
            $this->magentoProduct->setAttributeSetId($this->magentoProduct->getDefaultAttributeSetId());
            $this->magentoProduct->setStoreId(self::DEFAULT_STORE_ID);
            $this->magentoProduct->setTypeId('simple');
            $this->magentoProduct->setSku($productData['sku']);
            $this->magentoProduct->setName($productData['name']);
            $this->magentoProduct->setDescription($productData['description']);
            $this->magentoProduct->setShortDescription($productData['short_description']);
            $this->magentoProduct->setPrice(floatval($productData['price']));

            $this->magentoProduct->setCost(floatval($productData['cost']));
            $this->magentoProduct->setIsImported($productData['is_imported']);            
            $this->magentoProduct->setMfgpartno($productData['mfgpartno']);            
            $this->magentoProduct->setEtilizeProductId($productData['etilize_product_id']);
            $this->magentoProduct->setCondition($productData['condition']);
            $this->magentoProduct->setManufacturer($productData['manufacture']);

            $this->magentoProduct->setCategoryIds($productData['category_id']); // need to look these up
            $this->magentoProduct->setWeight($productData['weight']);
            $this->magentoProduct->setTaxClassId(self::DEFAULT_TAXCLASS); // taxable goods
            $this->magentoProduct->setVisibility(self::DEFAULT_VISIBILITY); // catalog, search
            $this->magentoProduct->setStatus(intval($productData['status'])); // enabled
            $this->magentoProduct->setCategoryIds($productData['category_id']);

            $this->magentoProduct->save();

            Mage::log("saving stock for new product");
              $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
                $stockItem->assignProduct($this->magentoProduct);
                $qty = (integer)$productData['qty'];
                $stockItem->setData('qty', $qty);
                $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', $qty > 0 ? 1:0);
                $stockItem->setData('stock_id', $productData['stock_id']);
                $stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 0);
                $stockItem->save();            



            }
            catch (Exception $e)
            {
                Mage::log("Failed Saving Product: " . $e->getMessage());
            }

            $magentoProductId=$this->magentoProduct->getId();
            unset($this->magentoProduct);
        }
        else
        {
            mage::log("UPDATING sku-" . $productData['sku']);
            try
            {


                $this->magentoProduct->setMfgpartno($productData['mfgpartno']);            
                $this->magentoProduct->setEtilizeProductId($productData['etilize_product_id']);
                $this->magentoProduct->setCondition($productData['condition']);
                $this->magentoProduct->setPrice(floatval($productData['price']));            
                $this->magentoProduct->setCost(floatval($productData['cost']));
                $this->magentoProduct->setWeight($productData['weight']);
                $this->magentoProduct->setTaxClassId($productData['tax_class_id']); 
                $this->magentoProduct->setManufacturer($productData['manufacture']); 

                $qty=(integer)$productData['qty'];
                $inStock=($qty > 0) ? 1 : 0;
                $stockData = $this->magentoProduct->getStockData();                
                $stockData['qty'] = $qty;
                $stockData['is_in_stock'] = $inStock;
                $stockData['manage_stock'] = 1;
                $stockData['use_config_manage_stock'] = 0;
                $this->magentoProduct->setStockData($stockData);               


                $this->magentoProduct->save();
            }
            catch (Exception $e)
            {
                Mage::log("Failed Update Product: " . $e->getMessage());
            }

            $magentoProductId=$this->magentoProduct->getId();
            unset($this->magentoProduct);
        }
        return $magentoProductId;
    }
```

This script is placed in a Magneto custom module and I have the product list in database table. I am selecting products from this table and update or insert into magento using the above script. The process is initializing by a curl request.I also tried to insert it in a batch of 100 or 50. Still gets the same error after updating or inserting around 3000 products. I am also changing the indexing mode to manual before running the process.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not for how many products inserted or updated together it's coming because of duplicate entry. So don't insert duplicate data. Magento database makes use of foreign key constraints to ensure database integrity. As an example, if a category is deleted, all categories below it in the category tree must be deleted too.

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

This error occurs because the data you are importing is provided table by table, row by row, without regard to the logical structure and integrity of the database.

I have faced same problem in one of my project for inserting product category, after that i have used proper checking functionality to avoid this type of error. My problem was i have used external id for category but some cases external id mismatched with original id.

You can do one thing, use Mage log (u are already using ) for inserting and updating to check after which product your importing is stopped . If you find the problem id then check all the data of this particular id and try to import/insert this particular data only using code. Find for which data the problem is coming and fix it. Let me know if i could help you more.

Comment: I already checked the products which gives constraint error, say 100 products, creating product doesn't give any error. but if i try to create 10,000 products then it gives constraint violation error after creating few thousand products.

Comment: I have created 30k products using code and i have faced this error only for duplicate entry of category id. But facing one problem till now it is 'memory exhausted issue'. Suppose if you started 10k product for insert but after 3k your the problem is occurred then u start your inserting from 3k to 4k if the problem is occurred again then i m sure it is only for duplicate entry otherwise not.

Answer (score 1):

to temporarily get rid of the problem you could turn off foreign keys in mysql, but this is of course no proper solution.  i would check wether the crash happens on create or update of a product. in case of create i would check if the product has an id after saving the new product, and only apply stock data if there is this id.  be careful with category ids in general. hope this helps a bit!